# Search Icon Not Showing Up Where It Needs To

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, icons

I have a search icon I am working on. Here is the code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:MyFirstApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        MyFirstApp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        MyFirstApp:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

When I run this code nothing shows up where the icon is supposed to. There is supposed to be an icon on the Action Bar. I have been having problems with the code **android:id="@+drawable/ic_action_search"**

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my MainActivityActions.java file:

```
package com.tyler.snux.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivityActions extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_actions);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is     present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely aren't inflating this in the proper actionBar menu.

Where are you referencing this `xml` from, can you post more code so I can edit this with proper code?

Comment: I know there is supposed to be a certain .png or .gif file that goes with this code right? I'm just having trouble getting it to work